# Oracle Apex how to access application items with global scope in multiple applications

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have established 2 globally scoped application items "USER_ID" and "USER_NAME" in an initial "portal" application ("App1"), which I want to use in multiple applications ("App2", "App3", etc) called from App1. I am using a common cookie name across each of the applications so session information is shared.

Though the 2 AI appear in session state in "App2", I'm having trouble using them on an "App2" page or in "App2" application processes or calculations.

I've tried using the various standard referencing methods to access the values of the global items, such as :USER_ID and &USER_ID., but trying to set a display-only page item source in "App2" to that value displays a null.

Is there a special referencing method or format I need to use in order to access the globally scoped variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sharing sessions with the authentication scheme cookie, you can share values of Application Items as long as

1. Items with the same name are defined in each application
2. Items have
   Scope = Global

[image: Application Item Scope]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the AI had to be defined in each app though that makes a lot of sense.